# ¿Cómo le asigno color a un JTextField en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield, color

Tengo una Matriz de X por X, si la posición 0,0 tiene 1 le debo asignar un color, la matriz está en un archivo txt, la leo con una matriz de texto pero el objeto tipo Color no me acepta texto.

Si mi Matriz fuera de tipo int color si me aceptaría la asignación

```
C1501.setBackground(MiColor[matriz[15][1]]);
```

¿Cómo lo convierto para que me lo acepte?

o ¿cómo puedo hacer mi matriz[][] y que aún así me lea los números del archivo de texto

```
    package matrizprueba;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class LeerMatriz extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int i;

    Color MiColor[] = {Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK};



    public LeerMatriz() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        C0101 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        C0102 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        C0103 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        C0201 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        C0202 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        C0203 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        C0301 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        C0302 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        C0303 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Leer Matriz");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Cargar");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(C0101, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(C0102, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(C0201, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(C0202, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(C0301, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(C0302, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(C0103, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(C0203, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(C0303, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addComponent(jButton1))))
                .addContainerGap(102, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(C0101, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(C0102, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(C0103, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(C0201, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(C0202, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(C0203, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(C0301, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(C0302, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(C0303, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap(78, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        Lectura();

    }                                        

    void Lectura() {
        File archivo = null;
        FileReader Fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        String matriz[][] = new String[4][4];

        try {
            archivo = new File("C:/TIENDA/MATRIZ.txt");
            Fr = new FileReader(archivo.toString());
            br = new BufferedReader(Fr);
            String linea;

            int numlinea = 0;

            while (((linea = br.readLine()) != null)) {

                String a[] = linea.split(",");

                for (int l = 0; l < a.length; l++) {
                    matriz[numlinea][l] = a[l];
                }
                numlinea++;
            }
            System.out.println("MATRIZ");
            System.out.println("------");
            for (int filas = 0; filas < matriz.length; filas++) {
                for (int colum = 0; colum < matriz[filas].length; colum++) {
                    System.out.print(matriz[filas][colum] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        int t = 0;
        int k = 0;

        //Ejemplo 
        //Da error, no me acepta mi matriz de String para asignarle color  
        C0101.setBackground(MiColor[String.valueOf(matriz[0][0])]); 

        // Con esto leo los numeros de la matriz, pero necesito que me le asigne color
        // a cada Jtextfield segun el numero que tenga en la posicion de la matriz, en vez
        // de que ne muestro los numeros que tiene
        C0101.setText(String.valueOf(matriz[0][0]));
        C0102.setText(String.valueOf(matriz[0][1]));
        C0103.setText(String.valueOf(matriz[0][2]));
        C0201.setText(String.valueOf(matriz[1][0]));
        C0202.setText(String.valueOf(matriz[1][1]));
        C0203.setText(String.valueOf(matriz[1][2]));
        C0301.setText(String.valueOf(matriz[2][0]));
        C0302.setText(String.valueOf(matriz[2][1]));
        C0303.setText(String.valueOf(matriz[2][2]));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LeerMatriz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LeerMatriz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LeerMatriz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LeerMatriz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LeerMatriz().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField C0101;
    private javax.swing.JTextField C0102;
    private javax.swing.JTextField C0103;
    private javax.swing.JTextField C0201;
    private javax.swing.JTextField C0202;
    private javax.swing.JTextField C0203;
    private javax.swing.JTextField C0301;
    private javax.swing.JTextField C0302;
    private javax.swing.JTextField C0303;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, cuando defines `MiColor` ¿a qué te refieres? según tu código, parece ser un arreglo (`MiColor[]`). ¿podrías brindarnos más información sobre ese dato?

Comment: Además, para indexar un valor en un arreglo, creo que querías decir `Integer.parseInt(matriz[0][0]);` y no `String.valueOf(matriz[0][0]);`

Comment: Pegue el código completo. 
MiColor es de la clase tipo Color..

Comment: ¿Lo que deseas, es cambiar el color al `JTextField` de acuerdo al número que se lee en tu archivo? O tu problema real es "`tipo Color no me acepta texto.`"?

Comment: @C.Rodriguez es correcto, cambiar el color al Jtextfield según el número que tenga la posición. Si la posición 0,0 tiene 1 en la matriz, al precionar el botón LEER MATRIZ asignarle color NEGRO al Jtextfield en vez de que me muestre el número 1.

Comment: Y si en caso de leer la matriz y en la posición 0,0 tiene 4, ¿qué debería pasar?

Comment: @C.Rodriguez daría error porque los únicos colores que tengo son BLANCO y NEGRO en MiColor. Habría que condicionarlo para evitar errores, pero por el momento solamente me interesa asignarle el color a las casillas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

Saludos, Joker.

Según indicas, deseas asignarle el color de tu arreglo `MiColor[]` a tu `JTextField`, si analizamos esta línea (que es precisamente donde obtienes tu error):

```
C0101.setBackground(MiColor[String.valueOf(matriz[0][0])]);
```

Estás intentando acceder a eso arreglo por medio de una cadena de texto y eso no es posible, para esto, primero deberías convertirlo a entero y no debes utilizar `String.valueOf`, sino `Integer.parseInt`, justo como te indiqué en los comentarios.

El motivo de esto se debe a que los arreglos necesitan de un índice de posición para obtener el valor almacenado en ese espacio, en tu caso, tu arreglo solo tiene 2 espacios, uno para el color negro y otro para el color blanco.

Esa línea de código debería quedar así:

```
C0101.setBackground(MiColor[Integer.parseInt(matriz[0][0])]);
```

Eso te podría generar error en caso de que el número que se lea de tu arreglo sea superior a la cantidad de elementos en tu arreglo `MiColor[]`, eso deberías controlarlo según la condición que indicaste en los comentarios.

Acá te adjunto el link de la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) para el método `Integer.parseInt` y de forma resumida:

> Convierte el argumento de texto (una cadena de texto) como un decimal entero con signo.

Comment: Mil gracias Rodriguez por ayuda, me funciono perfecto, gracias por la documentación, tengo mucho que leer. 
Saludos!.

Comment: Hola Rodríguez disculpa que te molesta, fíjate que el color solo me lo muestra en la posición [0][0], si lo pongo en la posición [0][1] o cualquier otra me da error.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te lanza?

Comment: No sé si este sea el motivo, pero viendo la forma en que lees tu archivo, los separas por `,` y todo está bien, solamente que los espacios en blancos entre las comas **también se toman en cuenta**, y si lo vemos de esa manera, si intentas convertir un espacio a un entero, te daría error de conversión

Comment: Podrías hacer esto, en el `for` donde lees el archivo encuentras esta línea: `matriz[numlinea][l] = a[l];`.    Déjala como esta: `matriz[numlinea][l] = a[l].trim();`. El método `trim` omite los espacios en blancos antes y después de la cadena de texto, así evitas también llevarte los espacios en el arreglo.

Comment: Gracias hermano, el error era: For Input String:  " 0" (de manera resumida), si era el espacio, pero ya lo tengo gracias a la línea que me pasaste. Gracias ✌️